# I am trying to get latest month salary from salary table, where multiple entry of employeeID in salary table for each month

Tags: mysql

Employee table"
**empno,
ename,
sal_id,
emp_id,
salary,
month**

SALARY table:

**sal_id,
emp_id,
salary,
month**

I am trying to make query for getting all employee from employee table +
In salary table, there are multiple entry (may be not) of emp_id.

I want employee list with their latest salary( or last month salary)

My current query is :

**SELECT * FROM `emp` LEFT JOIN `salary` ON `emp.empno` = `salary.emp_id` GROUP BY `empno` ORDER BY `salary.sal_id` DESC**

But I am getting emp list with first salary, I want with latest salary.

Help me :(
[Emploee table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC257.png)
[Salary table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE6Ho.png)

Comment: Do not post screenshots as attached images. Don't be too lazy to add relevant code in the question.

Comment: your order by is wrong try with Date or something else

Answer (score 0):

You are ordering by `sal_id` instead you might want to order by a field in `salary` which represents its month.

Comment: @SRDepp That's probably because you have months stored as string it seems. With that you will have alphabetical order only. You should use date type in your db.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT emp.empno, emp.name, (
        SELECT sal
        FROM salary
        WHERE salary.empno = emp.empno
        ORDER BY salary.sal_id DESC LIMIT 1
        )
FROM emp
```

Comment: Thanks But I want in single query no nested query

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. It’s because of helpful peers like yourself that we’re able to learn together as a community. Here are a few tips on how to make your answer great: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have come with solution after a lot R&D and googling .
It is not possible in single query, we have to apply 2 query

```
SELECT * FROM emp LEFT JOIN salary ON salary.emp_id=emp.empno WHERE salary.sal_id IN ( SELECT MAX(salary.sal_id) FROM salary GROUP BY salary.emp_id ) GROUP BY salary.sal_id ORDER BY salary.sal_id DESC
```